# String parsing up to a specific character (Python)

Tags: python

`Vogue (@voguemagazine) • Instagram photos and videos`

`Fashionista (@fashionista_com) • Instagram photos and videos`

`The Business of Fashion (@bof) • Instagram photos and videos`
I parsed the string inside the `<title>` tag in the Instagram's page.

I need to parse the screen name which is all strings before `(@....)` in the string above.

For my examples above, it will be `Vogue`, `Fashionista`, and `The Business of Fashion` respectively.

I tried something like

`string.split(' ')[0].replace('\n', '')` but this just parses the very first token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

module "re" will help. Please find below a pattern that makes this possible:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("(.+?) \(@.*?\)")

string = "Vogue (@voguemagazine) • Instagram photos and videos"
word = pattern.findall(string)[0]
```

In pattern "`(.+?) \(@.*?\)`"

- `(.+?)` - catches all characters before space ("") and parentheses;
- `\(@.*?\)` - catches
  things in parentheses (i.e. between "`(\`" and "`\)`"), e.g. "`@`"
  and all other characters ("`.*?`")